# Java, sending MouseEvents over socket, how can I do it?

Tags: java, sockets, mouseevent, mouselistener

I've tried implementing MouseListener and sending it over ObjectInputStream, but I don't have a sense of direction on how to make the server receive such actions, recognize what button is pressed, and act on it.

How can I send mouse events such as mousePressed from a client to a server, so that the server can perform the mouse events?

Client - Records mouse actions,
Server - Receives and Performs such actions.

Comment: Be careful to distinguish whether you want to serialize the _`MouseListener`_ or a _`MouseEvent`_.  The distinction matters quite a lot.

Comment: Having tried this years ago, I would like to advise against trying to do what you are trying to do. There are many issues you are going to run up against down the road... Like servers that don't have a screen so you can't actually run graphics operations on them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can only send serializable concepts over the wire and a mouselistener is unlikely to be.

You have code. You wish for this code to respond to the event.

For that to happen, the code and the information about the event (that it has occurred, i.e. that the user clicked, and the details about this event, i.e. where they clicked, which button they used, etc) have to be in the same place.

Bring the event to the code. Don't bring the code to the event. You serialize the MouseEvent, not the listener.

Have  MouseListener running on the client. This listener sends the relevant information about the event to the server. I wouldn't use ObjectXStream at all, but write an actual API of sorts, using e.g. JSON or protobuf or some other real protocol to talk to the server, preferably in HTTPS, as that tunnels and tests easier.

Comment: _You can only send serializable concepts over the wire and a mouselistener is unlikely to be._ `MouseListener` is an interface. Is there something preventing me from writing a `Serializable` class that implements `MouseListener`?

Comment: It would require the exact same class file to exist on both systems; ObjectOutputStream is not going to send this code around for you. I said 'unlikely to be', not 'this is impossible'. It's unlikely, and a bad idea. Not impossible.

Comment: I was confused writing this question on how to move MouseEvents across clients, I figured a way out.
Although I can only use Java in Eclipse and I don't really know anything else so I serialized an outer class containing mouse events and key events for my project, it is probably a bad solution but the only one I can think of.